# How to set up server when curl is returning error 60

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, curl, https

I have little problem with setting up our server.

I made XML feed for Facebook dynamic remarketing, but everytime when the Facebook is trying to download that feed it returns curl error 60. I know, that is a problem with SSL, but I was trying to update all certificates with command `update-ca-certificates --fresh` and it didn't help.

When I use this command, it returns proper response:

```
curl --url https://www.example.com --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

But when I use command without exact certification authority file

```
curl --url https://www.example.com
```

it returns this response:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the --cacert option. If this HTTPS server uses a certificate
>   signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate
>   verification probably failed due to a  problem with the certificate
>   (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the domain name in
>   the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the
>   certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option.

Our SSL provider is RapidSSL. I tried to add theirs ceritificate to cacert.pem, but it didn't work too.

Dou you have some suggestions how to fix this problem and how to properly set up server to correctly accept cUrl requests and correctly send response?

Thank you for your help.

## Edit

Eventually I found out, that my problem was in version of SSL. Facebook is no more supporting HTTPS communication on SSL version 3 from October 2014 so we had to change our security to TLS 1.2 and that was all. Hopefully it will help to somebody :-)

Comment: Try checking your domain's SSL setup with SSL Labs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Thanks, it helped ;-)